# Excel formula, IF certain day of week then add "x" number of days

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a formula for the following scenario.  I need to calculate date based on another column but need to add days based on day of the week of original column.

```
If day of week equals 'Mon/Wed/Fri/Sat' then add 5 days.
If day of week equals 'Tue' then add 6 days.
If day of week equals 'Thur" then add 4 days.
```

For example,

```
Column A  Column B
3/11/17   (Show date based on above scenario)
3/13/17
3/18/17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Choose:

```
=A1+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1,2),5,6,5,4,5,5,0)
```

So the Weekday(A1,2) converts the weekday to its position in the week starting with Monday being 1 and Sunday being 7.

The numbers are the number of days to add per day.

It then adds the chosen day to the date.

[image]

Comment: Really nice, simple way to do it

Comment: @Serge please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.